# Get Named instance of dependency

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have the following code:

```
        var container = new Container();

        //car
        container.Configure(
            x => x.For<ICar>().Use<Honda>());

        //engines
        container.Configure(x => x.For<IEngine>().Use<V8Engine>().Named("V8"));
        container.Configure(x => x.For<IEngine>().Use<V12Engine>().Named("V12"));

        var car = container.GetInstance<ICar>();

        Console.WriteLine(car.Name());
```

`IEngine` is an interface used by `ICar` concrete implementations and is injected in constructor.

Now by default StructureMap will use `V12Engine` but I want it to use `V8Engine` instead, how can I implement this scenario?

Comment: title should not contain tags: check this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution to this problem and I am giving it below in case anyone else needs it:

**Solution 1:**

```
        var car = container.With(container.GetInstance<IEngine>("V8")).GetInstance<ICar>();
```

**Solution 2:**

```
        var engine = new V8Engine();
        var car = container.With<IEngine>(engine).GetInstance<ICar>();
```

**Solution 3: (if you have lot of dependencies)**

```
        var engine = new V8Engine();

        var eArgs = new ExplicitArguments();
        eArgs.Set<IEngine>(engine);

        var car = container.GetInstance<ICar>(eArgs);
```

A more detailed explanation can be found here: http://structuremap.github.io/resolving/passing-arguments-at-runtime/